# Insert Query into postgresql using Table Adapter C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, datatableadapters

I am trying to insert data into a postgresql table in visual studio windows forms table adapter using this query;

```
    INSERT INTO PUBLIC .cashaccount
VALUES (:cashmemo, :cashcredit, :cashdebit)
```

I am using the ':' because I am aware the '@' operator does not work in postgresql but I am still getting a syntax error. I have googled this issue and I am yet to find a postgresql insert command with variables. Does anyone have an idea on how to make the above statement work?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @rahul 'syntax error at or near ":"'

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax error your are getting is due to the space in your table name as pointed below

```
INSERT INTO PUBLIC .cashaccount
                  ^----Here
VALUES (:cashmemo, :cashcredit, :cashdebit)
```

Also, read through [Npgsql(.NET Postgresql provider)](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/wiki/User-Manual) for more information with lots of examples.

Comment: The error is around the colon in front of the value 'syntax error at or near ":"'.Have checked other errors .Remember I am  writing the query in the TableAdapter which works if I substitute raw values like 'school',2000,3000 in place of :cashmemo,:cashcredit,:cashdebit respectively.